# Spring boot table to show list of pets by owner id

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jpa, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm making a small school project  Spring Boot web application. Right now I have made CRUD for Owners table in the database, what I'm trying to do next is when I click button "pets" I want to be able to show only those pets that has the same "owner_id". I guess I should receive "owner_id" from the button that was pressed. How can I make that it works the way it should work? Now when I press button "pets" it shows all list of the pets.

Owner class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "owners")
public class Owner {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
private String email;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Pet.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private List<Pet> pets;

public Owner() {
    
}

public Owner(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

Pet class:

```
@Table(name = "pets")
public class Pet {

@Id
private Long id;

private String name;

private String breed;

private int age;

private double weight;

public Pet() {
    
}

public Pet(String name, String breed, int age, double weight) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.age = age;
    this.weight = weight;
}
}
```

Controller method for list of pets:

```
@GetMapping("/owner_pets")
public String getAllPetsByOwnerId(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("pets", petService.getAllPetsByOwnerId());
    return "owner_pets";
}
```

Here is the code written so far but it only shows list of all pets

Comment: Can you share you service class method

Comment: This one is PetService
`package com.veterinary.Veterinary_system.service;`
`import java.util.List;`
`import com.veterinary.Veterinary_system.entity.Pet;`
`public interface PetService {`
`List<Pet> getAllPetsByOwnerId();`
`Pet savePet(Pet pet);`
`}`

Comment: And This one Is OwnerService code:
`package com.veterinary.Veterinary_system.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.veterinary.Veterinary_system.entity.Owner;

public interface OwnerService {
List<Owner> getAllOwners();
Owner saveOwner(Owner owner);
Owner getOwnerById(Long id);
Owner updateOwner(Owner owner);
void deleteOwnerById(Long id);
Owner findOwner(Long id);
}
`

Comment: Suggestion: Don't add relevant details (such as these code snippets) as comments. They are difficult to read (as you can see) - and, anyway, they belong in the body of the question. You can [edit] the question to add them, and then delete the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your service method for PerService. I do not see any ownerId being passed to findByOwnerId method. That might be the reason why you are getting all pets in response. What you should ideally do is

```
package com.veterinary.Veterinary_system.service;
import java.util.List;
import com.veterinary.Veterinary_system.entity.Pet;
public interface PetService {

//Repository declaration

    List < Pet > findByOwnerId(Long ownerId){
    return petRepository.findByOwnerId(ownerId);
}
    Pet savePet(Pet pet);
}
```